# How to predict Faster RCNN model in batches?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, prediction, faster-rcnn

I have a trained RCNN (Keras-Retinanet) model and I could predict only one image at a time.

```
boxes, scores, labels = model.predict_on_batch(np.expand_dims(image, axis=0))
```

Full script is [here](https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet/blob/master/examples/ResNet50RetinaNet.ipynb).

Is there a way to predict multiple images at a time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason you expand the dims there is to artificially add a batch dimension. Simply stack a bunch of images together and pass it into this function to get a batch of results.

Said differently, right now you are passing in:
[image].

You could instead pass in:
[image_1, image_2, image_3, ...] (as a numpy, not python array)

Comment: Tried but for this error:

`File "detector.py", line 85, in <module>
    boxes, scores, labels = model.predict_on_batch(image, image1, image2, image3)
TypeError: predict_on_batch() takes 2 positional arguments but 5 were given`

Comment: I also tried `imgs = []
imgs.append(image)
imgs.append(image1)` and got this error  `ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [800, 800, 3]`

Comment: You can't pass in a python list, you have to construct a tensor or numpy array of the appropriate shape. One way to do this is to expand the dim, then use numpy's append: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html